# Found some code for serialization of an ItemStack in Bukkit, how to deserialize it?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I've dug up the following code for serializing an `ItemStack` in bukkit (Minecraft). I've been able to serialize an item in hand with the following:

```
itemString = ItemStackUtils.deserialize(player.getInventory().getItemInHand());
```

I can't figure out how to utilize the `deserial` call however. What I am trying to do is to pull an item from the players hand, serialize it, stick it into a config file, then when the player runs another command... deserialize it and slap it into their inventory. I am fairly certain this class will meet my needs if I just can get the last part working.

```
public final class ItemStackUtils {
    public static String getEnchants(ItemStack i){
        List<String> e = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<Enchantment, Integer> en = i.getEnchantments();
        for(Enchantment t : en.keySet()) {
            e.add(t.getName() + ":" + en.get(t));
        }
        return StringUtils.join(e, ",");
    }
    public static String deserialize(ItemStack i){
        String[] parts = new String[6];
        parts[0] = i.getType().name();
        parts[1] = Integer.toString(i.getAmount());
        parts[2] = String.valueOf(i.getDurability());
        parts[3] = i.getItemMeta().getDisplayName();
        parts[4] = String.valueOf(i.getData().getData());
        parts[5] = getEnchants(i);
        return StringUtils.join(parts, ";");
    }
    public ItemStack deserial(String p){

        String[] a = p.split(";");
        ItemStack i = new ItemStack(Material.getMaterial(a[0]), Integer.parseInt(a[1]));
        i.setDurability((short) Integer.parseInt(a[2]));
        ItemMeta meta = i.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName(a[3]);
        i.setItemMeta(meta);
        MaterialData data = i.getData();
        data.setData((byte) Integer.parseInt(a[4]));
        i.setData(data);
        if (a.length > 5) {
            String[] parts = a[5].split(",");
            for (String s : parts) {
                String label = s.split(":")[0];
                String amplifier = s.split(":")[1];
                Enchantment type = Enchantment.getByName(label);
                if (type == null)
                    continue;
                int f;
                try {
                    f = Integer.parseInt(amplifier);
                } catch(Exception ex) {
                    continue;
                }
                i.addEnchantment(type, f);
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

here it saves & loads the whole NBT

```
package XXXXXXXXX

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_8_R3.inventory.CraftItemStack;
import org.bukkit.enchantments.Enchantment;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.inventory.meta.ItemMeta;
import org.bukkit.material.MaterialData;

import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MojangsonParseException;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.MojangsonParser;
import net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.NBTTagCompound;

public class ItemSerialize {

    public ItemSerialize() {
    }

    public static String serialize(ItemStack i) {
        String[] parts = new String[7];
        parts[0] = i.getType().name();
        parts[1] = Integer.toString(i.getAmount());
        parts[2] = String.valueOf(i.getDurability());
        parts[3] = i.getItemMeta().getDisplayName();
        parts[4] = String.valueOf(i.getData().getData());
        parts[5] = getEnchants(i);
        parts[6] = getNBT(i);
        return StringUtils.join(parts, ";");
    }

    public static String getEnchants(ItemStack i) {
        List<String> e = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<Enchantment, Integer> en = i.getEnchantments();
        for (Enchantment t : en.keySet()) {
            e.add(t.getName() + ":" + en.get(t));
        }
        return StringUtils.join(e, ",");
    }

    public static String getLore(ItemStack i) {
        List<String> e = i.getItemMeta().getLore();
        return StringUtils.join(e, ",");
    }

    public static String getNBT(ItemStack i) {

        net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ItemStack nmsStack = CraftItemStack.asNMSCopy(i);
        NBTTagCompound compound = nmsStack.hasTag() ? nmsStack.getTag() : new NBTTagCompound();
        return compound.toString();

    }

    public static ItemStack setNBT(ItemStack i, String NBT) {

        net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.ItemStack nmsStack = CraftItemStack.asNMSCopy(i);
        try {
            NBTTagCompound compound = MojangsonParser.parse(NBT);

            nmsStack.setTag(compound);
        } catch (MojangsonParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        return CraftItemStack.asBukkitCopy(nmsStack);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static ItemStack deserial(String p) {

        String[] a = p.split(";");
        ItemStack i = new ItemStack(Material.getMaterial(a[0]), Integer.parseInt(a[1]));
        i.setDurability((short) Integer.parseInt(a[2]));
        ItemMeta meta = i.getItemMeta();
        meta.setDisplayName(a[3]);
        i.setItemMeta(meta);
        MaterialData data = i.getData();
        data.setData((byte) Integer.parseInt(a[4]));
        i.setData(data);
        if (!a[6].isEmpty()) {
            i = setNBT(i, a[6]);
        }
        if (!a[5].isEmpty()) {
            String[] parts = a[5].split(",");
            for (String s : parts) {
                String label = s.split(":")[0];
                String amplifier = s.split(":")[1];
                Enchantment type = Enchantment.getByName(label);
                if (type == null)
                    continue;
                int f;
                try {
                    f = Integer.parseInt(amplifier);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    continue;
                }
                i.addUnsafeEnchantment(type, f);
            }
        }

        return i;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ItemStack rItem = ItemStackUtils.deserial(itemString);
```

Comment: Please consider expanding this answer so that it will be useful to other users.

Comment: This answer is incorrect as `itemString` has not been defined.